# Create dict (key: list of objects) from list of objects using value of object as key

Tags: python

I have the following list of objects (simplified)

where object is a class

```
from dataclasses import @dataclass

@dataclass
class LinkObject:
    id: int
    link_id: int
    name: str


list_of_obs = [
    LinkObject(1, 2, 'a'),
    LinkObject(2, 2, 'b'),
    LinkObject(3, 3, 'c'),
    LinkObject(4, 3, 'd'),
]
```

I would like to convert the above into the following dict (key is link_id in object above: -

```
{
    2: [
        LinkObject(id=1, link_id=2, name='a'),
        LinkObject(id=2, link_id=2, name='b'),
    ], 
    3: [
        LinkObject(id=3, link_id=3, name='c'),
        LinkObject(id=4, link_id=3, name='d'),
    ]
}
```

What is the correct way to do this using comprehension?

Ive tried : -

```
a_dict = {i.link_id: [i] for i in list_of_obs}
```

which is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: _"i believe its incorrect"_ - why _believe_? Did you _try it_? What happened? Given the syntax error you should be pretty _certain_ it's not correct.

Comment: What are the values of the variables `link_id`, `id`, `name`, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`?  Should those be string literals?

Comment: Please clarify the point raised by @Samwise. Or do you mean to write `id`, `link_id` etc., as edited by @Tim (if not, the edit can be rolled back).

Comment: @Samwise the values are as written . The object has 2 ints and a string

Comment: You are only half-addressing the point raised, although the correct answer is apparent from your edit. Apparently *all* of `link_id`, `id`, `name`, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are in fact `str` values: `"link_id"` etc. Please be careful about this in your code. Also, general advice: don't use `dict` (or `id`, or `list`) as a variable. `dict` and `list` are built-in data types in Python (and  `id` a built-in function), which your code is overwriting. E.g. use `a_dict`, or something like that, etc.

Comment: @ouroboros1 the above is simplified and changed for the example. the variable name is not called 'dict' - i take your point. list_of_obs contains obects with 3 class fields - id, link_id and name. id and link_id are both type ints, name is type string. a , b c and d are the values of name in each of the objects

Comment: The edit was not syntactically valid Python, but your intent was adequately clear that I was able to rewrite it as a `@dataclass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up discovering a much simpler solution using a default dict which produces the required dict that i need.

```
def get_dict_of_links(
    links: list[LinkObject],
) -> dict[int, list[LinkObject]]:

    dict_of_links = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in links:
        dict_of_links[obj.link_id].append(obj)
    return dict_of_links
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary values should be accessed via square bracket notation:

```
i['link_id']
```

To actually put divide the list of objects into groups, you would need a loop or you can use the `itertools` package.

Using loop:

```
d = {}
for i in list_of_obs:
    # get the existing list for link_id, or create a new list for the link_id if not seen before
    lst = d.get(i['link_id'], [])
    lst.append(i)
    d[i['link_id']] = lst
```

Using `itertools`:
one caveat is that you need to sort the list_of_obs by `'link_id'` for groupby to work correctly.

```
from itertools import groupby
list_of_obs_sorted = sorted(list_of_obs, key=lambda i: i['link_id'])
d = {name: list(group) for name, group in groupby(list_of_obs_sorted, key=lambda i: i['link_id'])}
```

Comment: Your edit seems to me premature (and hence also your answer), What the OP wrote (simplified), is:  `d = {name: a}`. The OP has given no indication that `name` or `a` are strings. And it's perfectly possible that they are in fact variables. If I write `name, a = 'my_name', 'tim'`, then declare `d` and finally, print `d`, then all of this will be working just fine. Whether it is generally a good idea is a different matter.

Comment: @ouroboros1 the edit may be premature, but the answer should work regardless, it would generate the target OP wants.

Comment: It does not work regardless, since `i['link_id']` would have caused a `KeyError: 'link_id'` if `link_id` would have been a variable storing some other string than `"link_id"`. But with the clarification of the OP, your `itertools` solution indeed does the job nicely. Maybe you want to have another look at the first `using loop`-snippet, though. This doesn't lead to a proper solution.

Comment: @ouroboros1 nice catch, fixed the `using loop` snippet.

Comment: Yes. Does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple of nested comprehensions:

```
obs_by_link_id = {
    link_id: [o for o in list_of_obs if o['link_id'] == link_id]
    for link_id in {o['link_id'] for o in list_of_obs}
}
```

which gives you:

```
obs_by_link_id == {
    2: [
        {'id': 1, 'link_id': 2, 'name': 'a'},
        {'id': 2, 'link_id': 2, 'name': 'b'}
    ],
    3: [
        {'id': 3, 'link_id': 3, 'name': 'c'},
        {'id': 4, 'link_id': 3, 'name': 'd'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: This answer has solved my problem thanks. i amended slightly as my initial code question wasnt as clear as it should have been.

Comment: `obs_by_link_id = {
        link_id: [o for o in list_of_obs if o.link_id == link_id]
        for link_id in {o.link_id for o in list_of_obs}
    }`